# Como exibir marker no mapa de acordo com o botão selecionado?

Tags: java, android, maps

Pesquisei e tentei algumas alternativas, mas não tive sucesso até o momento.

*Gostaria de exibir os "markers" de acordo com o botão pressionado na tela principal. Por exemplo:
A) botão 1 resulta em exibir o mapa apenas com "local a".
B) botão 2 resulta em exibir o mapa apenas com o "local b".

*O que consegui: vincular os botões ao mapa  e exibir "todos" os markers. Não desejado.

Segue o código resumido:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
;

        // Criando dois locais (A e B :
        LatLng localA = new LatLng(-5.8702316, -35.2079593);
        LatLng localB = new LatLng(-5.8843777, -35.1747881);

        //Inserindo pinos (markers) baseado nos locais criados:
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(localA)
                .title("Aqui é o local A")//título
                .snippet("Confirme por Tel.: 5555-5555")//subtítulo
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))//cor
                .visible(true));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(localB)
                .title("Aqui é o local B”)//título
                .snippet("Confirme por Tel.: 5555-5555")//subtítulo

                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))//cor

                .visible(true)); 

       if(ENTRAR PELO BOTAO 1)

              Exibir o “Local A” e ocultar o “Local B”:

                     LocalA.visible(true)

                     LocalB.visible(false)



       if(ENTRAR PELO BOTAO 2)

              Exibir o “Local B” e ocultar o “Local A”:            

                     LocalA.visible(false)

                     LocalB.visible(true)
        //Local padrão para abertura do mapa:                       mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom((localA), 12));//zoo de 12 no local A

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui descobrir verificando no livro de Ricardo Lecheta, sobre passagem de parâmetros entre Activities (telas), segue a solução:

Arquivo MainActivity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Button v1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    //Click de um botão qualquer:

    v1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //TROCA DE TELAS:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);

            //Passagem de parâmetros para a tela seguinte:
            Bundle params = new Bundle();//declaração
            params.putString("nome", "um");//uso do metodo .putString("chave", "string desejada para ser comparada na tela seguinte")

        //Passagem por parâmetro --> Aqui é onde a mágica acontece:
            intent.putExtras(params);

        //Trocando de tela:
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Tela 2 - MapsActivity.java:

(...)

//Utilizando a opção do botao passada por parâmetro - Final da mágica:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle args = intent.getExtras();
    String n = args.getString("nome");//capturando a chave para receber a string associada a essa chave.

    String um = "um",
            dois = "dois",
            tres = "tres";

    //Exibindo o pino de acordo com o botao clicado na tela anterior:

    if (n.equals(um)) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(neopolis)
                .title("Nome do local")
                .visible(true)
        //Subtítulo:
                .snippet("Confirme por Tel.: 5555-5555")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
        //Foco do mapa:
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom((neopolis), 12));
    }
```

Testado e funcionando perfeitamente no PC e celular.

Answer (score 2):

Se quer controlar a visibilidade da Marker depois de ela ser adiciona tem de ter uma referência a ela.

A referência pode ser obtida na altura em que é usado o método `addMarker()`.

```
//Inserindo pinos (markers) baseado nos locais criados:
Marker markerA = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(localA)
        .title("Aqui é o local A")//título
        .snippet("Confirme por Tel.: 5555-5555")//subtítulo
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))//cor
        .visible(true));

Marker markerB mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(localB)
        .title("Aqui é o local B”)//título
        .snippet("Confirme por Tel.: 5555-5555")//subtítulo

        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))//cor

        .visible(true));
```

Use `markerA.visible()` e `markerB.visible()` para alterar a visibilidade.

Se pretender usá-las fora do método `onMapReady()` declare-as como campos da Activity/Fragment

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu vínculo aos 2 If que estão na parte final código?

Comment: Não entendi. O que quer dizer com "como eu vínculo aos 2 If"?

Comment: Quero vincular o estado, de visível ou não visível, ao botão que foi selecionado na tela anterior do app. E cada "If" verifica se o botão 1 ou 2 foi pressionado pelo usuário.

Comment: Não sabe construir o `if`? Se sabe onde está `LocalA.visible(true)` e `LocalB.visible(false)` substitua por `markerA.visible(true)` e `markerB.visible(false)`.

Comment: Não sei implementara a verificação da condição do "If": if(ENTRAR PELO BOTAO 1) ou if(ENTRAR PELO BOTAO 2)

Comment: Deve criar outra pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes para que possamos perceber o que exactamente pretende fazer. Parece-me(não tenha a certeza) que o que necessita é implementar o método `onClick()` de cada um dos botões.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79988/discussion-between-luiz-and-ramaral).